# Handle different Request by a Single Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

My servlet is like this

```
@WebServlet(name = "login", urlPatterns = {"/login"})
public class login extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        password = Base64.encode(password.getBytes());
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setPassword(password);
        user.getLoggedIN();
}
```

according to this servlet i can use "login" and send GET or POST data to this servelt it is perfectly ok
my question is, is there a way that i can use this servelt and direct different request.
example

1. 'login' (with post request will execute ) -> doPost() method (i know that doPost)
2. 'signout' (with post request will execute) -> another method defined and it will act as a doPost method

i don't know wheter this is possible!

Answer (score 3):

- I think you will have the names of the `SignOut` and `Login` buttons.
  So, when you click one of them, at your `Servlet` you can check which
  `button` was actually clicked by invoking `request.getParameter()` on
  button names, and then forward the request to appropriate method..

So, at your `servlet`, you can have this kind of a code: -

```
if (request.getParameter("LoginButton") != null) {
     // Forward to login method

} else if(request.getParameter("SignOutButton") != null) {
     //Forward to signout method..
}
```

- Another way would be to send the name of `Button` as a `Query
  String`... And you can fetch the name in `servlet` from that query
  string using `request.getParameter()`

So your **query string** look like:

```
http://localhost:8080/yourServlet?action=Login
http://localhost:8080/yourServlet?action=SignOut
```

Answer (score 1):

What I have done in similar situation is as follows:

1. Use a hidden field describing what kind of operation i want to perform(e.g. login,logout,enter data, update data etc whatever you want)
2. Retrieve the value of hiddden parameter from request object.
3. Use if else ladder for each possible operation and then call appropriate method in the if else block.

I know this is very basic,but hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Add another pattern. Check for request parameters that are unique to each type of request or you can also verify whether it is login or signpost request using 'request.getRequestURI' method

Answer (score -1):

see according to general scenario  post we are using
for submits data to be processed (e.g., from an HTML form) to the identified resource. The data is included in the body of the request. This may result in the creation of a new resource or the updates of existing resources or both.

So In UI you will insert the data and that particular data you can also see
in database.
 Here in your code

```
 @Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    password = Base64.encode(password.getBytes());
    User user = new User();
    user.setUsername(username);
    user.setPassword(password);
    user.getLoggedIN();
```

only getting data you are setting.
or you can use

```
if(user!=null){
```

//here you can forward your request some where.
}